# Django call_command() parameter type issue

Tags: python, django, command

When I try to call my custom django command with a id as a string it works without a problem.

```
call_command(COMMAND, '-i', '23')
```

But when I try to cast the id of a object to a string, then it will not work.

```
call_command(COMMAND, '-i', str(product.id))
```

It become this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 423, in __call__
    return self.__value__
AttributeError: 'ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Try `print str(product.id)` before the `call_command`

Comment: It gives me this: 23

Comment: What puzzles me is the shortness of the stack trace. It implies `__init__.py` has been called directly.

Answer (score 0):

This function is inside a test, adding @override_settings(DEBUG=True) helped. The command is calling a task, so I had to made sure that it's not triggering the task.delay

Still strange that it worked with just putting the string as a parameter...

Comment: In that case your question missed most of the parts to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also you should not use answers to add informations / clarifications - use comments and / or edit your question instead.